# I need to correct this line error in the code, though when I 'run' the script no errors are reported

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone

lines 54-56:

```
54 -     if (today == Utilities.formatDate(files[i].getLastUpdated(), "EST", "yyyy-MM-dd")) 
         {
55 -     Logger.log("  -> File was modified today. Getting word count...");
56  -    word_count += getFileWordCount(files[i].getId());
```

error message from google reads:

> getDailyWordCount Bad value (line 55, file "Code")    time-based

I am thinking the problem is with the "EST" since I am not in that time zone. I am in GMT+3:00

Here is the script and how it is supposed to function - https://github.com/jamietr1/google-docs-writing-tracker

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change your timezone to:

1. getScriptTimeZone()
2. Use timezone as the format documented in: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
   or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

Comment: @Molks' No I havent as I am very new to this and I didnt want to 'mess' with the code, and get myself in more trouble. I orginally documented the error(s) here | https://github.com/jamietr1/google-docs-writing-tracker/issues/19 | but did not get any clarity on them so i came here.